# Issue while creating Foreign Key constraint

Tags: python, django, python-3.9, django-3.2

**Issue Details**

> 'Can't create table `django`.`clientauth_tblusers` (errno: 150
> "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')

**What am I doing?**

I created a tinyint auto increment field below but when referencing it in another table causing issue.

**Code in Model file**

```
class TinyIntField(AutoField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "tinyint(3) AUTO_INCREMENT"

class tblroles(models.Model):
    role_id = TinyIntField(primary_key=True, verbose_name = "role_id")
    name = CharField(max_length = 20)

class tblusers(models.Model):
    user_id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    role = ForeignKey(tblroles, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

**Code in Migration File**

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='tblroles',
    fields=[
        ('role_id', clientauth.models.TinyIntField(primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='role_id')),
        ('name', models.CharField(max_length=20))
    ],
),
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='tblusers',
    fields=[
        ('user_id', models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
        ('role', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='clientauth.tblroles')),
    ],
),
```

**Bounty Question**

> on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='clientauth.tblroles'

This line in above code doesn't set cascade delete database side. I checked docs but could not find one that set the cascade delete. Can you suggest one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `rel_db_type` to return similar to `db_type` without `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```py
class TinyIntField(AutoField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "tinyint(3) AUTO_INCREMENT"

    def rel_db_type(self, connection):
        return "tinyint(3)"
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-database-types

Comment: bounty question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69611485/react-to-django-cors-issue